# strong params JSON API specification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, json-api

I am working to an REST API in Rails 5.2 and I'm following the JSON API specification. My JSON are like this:

```
{  
  "data":{  
    "attributes":{  
      "name":"Gleydson",
      "age":"30"
    },
    "relationships":{  
      "occupation":{  
        "data":{  
          "attributes": {
             "name": "Teacher",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have the following method **user_params**:

```
    params.require(:data).require(:attributes)
        .permit(:name, :age, 
       relationships: { occupation: { data: { attributes: [:name] } } })
```

but when I print the return of the method nothing is returned

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using a gem to go from Ruby objects to JSON:API serialized ones. [JSONAPI::Resources](http://jsonapi-resources.com/v0.10/guide/controllers.html) helps a lot with getting the params right since you just define a JSONAPI:Resource and tell it what to allow.

I think part of your problem is that in JSON:API the attributes and relationships keys are siblings

user_params: `{data:{attributes:{name:x,age:y,relationships:{z}}}}`

jsonapi is:  `{data:{attributes:{name:x,age:y},relationships:{z}}}`

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON API spec "attributes" and "relationships" are siblings.

In your example you have nested "relationships" inside of "attributes".

Instead try:

```
params.require(:data).permit({
  attributes: [:name, :age], 
  relationships: { 
    occupation: { 
      data: { 
        attributes: [:name]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the [spec](https://jsonapi.org/format), attributes should not show up under a relationship's data member. A relationship's data member is a resource identifier object, meaning it only (and must only) contain type and id.

For JSON:API compliance checking, you may want to check out the new ruby gem [easy-jsonapi](https://github.com/Curatess/easy-jsonapi). It has a middleware and response validator that is super easy to use with intuitive error messages to tell you why your documents, requests, and responses are not compliant. It also pairs well with [JSONAPI-SERIALIZER](https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer), which as @robertoplancarte was suggesting, could take your ruby objects and serialize them into JSON:API compliant JSON documents.